# Using exec throws process error after save in node webkit

Tags: node.js, filesystems, exec, node-webkit

I'm using `exec()` in node webkit to open a file in the operating system's default program using `start filename` after it saves the file. Here is my code:

```
            var fs = require('fs');
            var myFile = "C:/TEMP/" + fileName;
            fs.writeFile(myFile, rtf, function(err) {
                if(err) {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
            var sys = require('sys');
            var exec = require('child_process').exec;
            var child;

            child = exec("start " + myFile, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
              if (error !== null) {
                console.log('exec error: ' + error);
              }
            });
```

Sometimes it works, but sometimes I'm getting this error: `exec error: Error: Command failed: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`

Edit: I saw that Microsoft has this issue with rtf and txt documents opening in wordpad (which is what mine was being opened in), so I thought it might have been that process hanging up and not dying properly. Before I called it quits for the night, I changed the default program to open in Libre Office and had better results (it didn't happen as often), but if I tried to fire the function quickly in sequence, I would still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

`writeFile` is async. You need a callback like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var myFile = "C:/TEMP/" + fileName;
fs.writeFile(myFile, rtf, function(err) {
   if(err) {
      alert("error");
   }else{
      lire();
   });

var sys = require('sys');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child;
function lire(){
   child = exec("start " + myFile, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
   if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
   }
   });
};
```

Comment: I just edited my post with something that I found relating to MS and wordpad. Thanks for the post, I will edit my post tomorrow when I put this into my app and share my results.